# How to undersand quantization of spin given spin's vector/spinor quality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, discrete

Suppose I have a photon source that emits two photons. One of them goes north, the other one goes northwest. I know that photons have spin {-1, 1}, and that integer spins are vectors. I want to calculate the total spin of my two photon system. If I take the vector sum and extract its scalar value, I get a total spin of
$$\sqrt{(1\pm \cos(\pi/4))^2 + (\cos(\pi/4))^2}$$
which isn't an integer or half-integer. But I thought spin was quantized for any given system, not just for individual particles.

So it seems like I've misunderstood something. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: The integers refer to eigenstates of the spin operator. However, photons can be in superpositions of these eigenstates. For system consisting of two photons propagating in different directions the situation become rather more complicated.

Comment: Please share the process you used to attempt to calculate the spin. Are you trying calculate the expectation value or what?

Comment: No, just simple vector addition of two unit vectors separated by an angular distance of pi/4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to calculate the total spin of my two photon system

As you do not state how this two photon system is created, it has no meaning to add the spins. Spins are quantum mechanical eigenvalues that appear when the angular momentum operator is applied to the wavefunctions of the system. Adding spins of two incoherent photons has no meaning and quantum numbers cannot be checked.

Take the simple example of the decay of a pi0 to two gamma. There exists a wavefunction for the system and no matter where or when the photons are (if they have not interacted), always their spin will add up to zero, the spin of the pi0.

Comment: [1/2] 
Let me see if I can phrase this in a way that makes sense to me to see if I've understood. 

The incoherent two-photon system does have spins whose sum comes to a non-quantized value (or a superposition of possible spins all combinations of which are non-quantized) but we don't care, because the photons aren't united by an event. So talking about the shared quantum numbers of the system isn't meaningful. More generally, systems that aren't united by an event can happily have subsystems whose eigenvalues sum to values that wouldn't be allowed if they were united by an event.

Comment: [2/2] For a more concrete example, if I fling an electron at an ion with an "up" orbital open, the likelihood that the electron just happens to have the perfect spin spinor to land in that slot is very low. But if the electron sticks to the ion, the electron will end up in the correct spin state, the ion will end up with its previous spin plus 1/2 ħ and the ion will pay the difference between the electron's previous spinor direction and its new spinor direction by slightly adjusting the orientation of the whole ion. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It is all about being able to write down a quantum mechanical wavefunction for the whole interacting system that will give the probabilities of interaction, on which the operators could be applied to give the quantum numbers. and then conservation of quantum numbers would have meaning.